# How is "instrument" pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation

I know how it's pronounced

But yesterday I came across a website for learning English .. and it was good

But in this page 
" 
http://www.learn-english-kids.net/page/6/
"

there is a word which is "instruments" and it is pronounced like there is a "sh" sound .. but I have not ever heard this word prounounced like this way !

is it about dialects or accents? or something else ?

Comment: I tried but i couldn't.. there is a small paragraph..   with audio in the form of flash file .. or something like that .. you can go to that page and play the audio .. there is no compilication .. so simple :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This pronunciation comes about because the speaker is making a conscious and awkward effort to speak very slowly and distinctly. This leads her to ‘overarticulate’—to exaggerate the separation of sounds which in natural speech flow into each other.

The unnatural attempt to distinguish the sounds at the n/s boundary in *instruments' causes her to anticipate the following /t/, because in all three sounds the tip of the tongue is placed at very similar places behind and above the front teeth. The glide is garbled, and /ns/ becomes /ntʃ/, as in *inch*.

Comment: Got it.. But if I pronounce this word quickly as the way in the link I gave .. will it seem weird? not natural?

Comment: @Maher It is, as you perceived, a mispronunciation, so you should not try to emulate it. But in fact if you do accidentally pronounce it this way while speaking normally in all other respects, chances are that nobody will notice. Native speakers of any language have trained their brains not to notice such errors, unless the error is so extreme that they can make no senes of it.